# Why does the add_roles() method from discord.py fail here?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, discord.py, python-asyncio

The following method is called on a discord bot thread from a flask application. All the print checks display the correct data so the method is being run successfully, however the final fstring

```
f'{role} added to {member}'
```

Does not get outputted to the console, which makes me think the

```
await member.add_roles(role)
```

Is not executing properly. No errors show up in the console. Every other line seems to run properly. Ive included the relevant methods below including the way the threads are structured in the flask app

```
client_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, members=True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', help_command=None, intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} is online!')
    return

async def start_bot():
    print(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
    await client.start(os.getenv("TOKEN"))


def run_it_forever(loop):
    loop.run_forever()

async def api_add_role(user, role_to_assign):
    guild = client.guilds[0]
    members = await guild.fetch_members(limit=None).flatten()
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=role_to_assign)
    print("role")
    print(role)
    member = [m for m in members if m.name == user][0]
    print("member")
    print(member)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    print(f'{role} added to {member}')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/add_role")
def add_role_to_member():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    role = request.args.get('role')
    coroutine = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(api_add_role(name, role), client_loop)
    return "okay"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_child_watcher()
    client_loop.create_task(start_bot())
    botThread = threading.Thread(target=run_it_forever, args=(client_loop,))
    def interrupt():
        global botThread
        botThread.join()
    atexit.register(interrupt)
    botThread.start()
    print("server starting....")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: One more thing, you seem to be using a flask server to handle your API. That probably isn't necessary. Your code already has access to whatever you are doing, so there is no need for any API stuff in there. You could just let the flask server run in its own thread to make it so that the bot never goes offline, though.

Comment: its for sure nessecary

Comment: The bot needs to run from its own process within flask. Please, if you dont understand the code you are reading its better to just not engage with the question

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Ill put another answer and hopefully it better helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anyone using your method to get the member object. There is [`get_member_named`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_member_named#discord.Guild.get_member_named) which is meant for that.

```py
async def api_add_role(user, role_to_assign):
    guild = client.guilds[0]

    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=role_to_assign)
    print(f"role: {role}")

    member = guild.get_member_named(user) # name or name#tag
    print(f"Member: {member}")

    if member and role: # if both exist
        await member.add_roles(role)
        print(f'{role.name} added to {member.name}')
```

Comment: Hmm thanks. Wasnt aware. This is just me following my thought process and reading the documentation. It works anyway, the correct member is selected and outputted in the print statement. But thanks for the tip

Comment: Did the role get added?

Comment: nope. the method i use is selecting the correct member object also. the problem seems to be with the await call. it never returns. im not sure why

Comment: So does it print the correct role and member? but don't add it?

Comment: correct yeah. im thinking its some sort of bug with using an await statement inside an asyncio subroutine but cant find anything on it